# AFHTTPClient.m no longer in AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am following a tutorial (http://bit.ly/1dbLaPh) that uses AFNetworking.  It says to make a new class that is subclassed from AFHTTPClient.  This option does not appear in the SubClass Of" field.  I checked the AFNetworking folder and there is no AFHTTPClient.m implementation file.  Has this file been renamed to something else?

thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In AFNetworking 2.0 the AFHTTPClient has been replaced by AFHTTPRequestOperationManager / AFHTTPSessionManager. I would suggest you to refer the [example](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example). Git clone and open in XCode. It should help you. That has the most updated example.

If you want to use AFHTTPClient i.e 1.x code. Here is the [git link to the branch](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x/Example). The pod spec to that would be

```
pod 'AFNetworking',  '~> 1.3.3'
```

In 2.0 AFNetworking, you can create a singleton client like this.

## interface

```
@interface AFAppDotNetAPIClient : AFHTTPSessionManager

+ (instancetype)sharedClient;

@end
```

## Implementation

```
#import "AFAppDotNetAPIClient.h"

static NSString * const AFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString = @"https://alpha-api.app.net/";

@implementation AFAppDotNetAPIClient

+ (instancetype)sharedClient {
    static AFAppDotNetAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[AFAppDotNetAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString]];
        [_sharedClient setSecurityPolicy:[AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

@end
```

Comment: Also checkout the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide)