# Use of undeclared identifier AFHTTPClient

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Hi I am trying to compile following code but getting error `Use of undeclered identifier AFHTTPClient`:

```
NSData* fileNameData = [fileName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *sendDictionary =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fileNameData forKey:@"fileName"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient =
    [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:@"http://www.olcayertas.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest =
    [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
        path:@"/photos"
        parameters:sendDictionary
        constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:photoImageData
                name:self.fileName.text
                fileName:filePath
                mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

}];

[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    //NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString); //Gives a very scary warning
}];

[operation start];
```

I am useing CocoaPods and here is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '7'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'AFNetworking/NSURLSession', '~> 2.0'
```

Comment: What are your `#import`s?

Comment: AfNetworking 2.0 remove AFHTTPClient

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503750/afhttpclient-m-no-longer-in-afnetworking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're including AFNetworking 2.0, but `AFHTTPClient` doesn't exist in 2.0 - it was a 1.0 feature. Check the [migration guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide) but `AFHTTPClient` has been replaced by `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

Also take a look at the [example app](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example/Classes) for 2.0 - `AFAppDotNetAPIClient` now subclasses `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

Answer (score 4):

In AFNetworking 3.0 you need to use AFHTTPSessionManager instead of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, because AFHTTPRequestOperationManager was removed